# How to read the machine code in linux crash info

Tags: assembly, crash, linux-kernel

There are machine codes in linux crash info.
Is there any tool can translate these machine codes to assembly instructions?

```
code of(ffffffffa0f04ce2):
0xc3 0x89 0xfa 0x66 0xed 0x0f 0xb7 0xc0 0xc3 0x89 0xfa 0xed 0xc3 0xf0 0x48 0x0f
```

Comment: If it is machine code it depends on the processor family...

Comment: yeah,so there is a online version can support kindes of cpu:http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/run_hex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a disassembler. I found one [online](http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/run_hex). Copy, Edit and paste `c3 89 fa 66 ed 0f b7 c0 c3 89 fa ed c3 f0 48 0f`, choose processor family (they have plenty to choose from) and you get the result. I tried with i386 and got the following:

```
c3      ret
89fa    mov %edi,%edx
66ed    in (%dx),%ax
0fb7c0  movzwl %ax,%eax
c3      ret
89fa    mov %edi,%edx
ed      in (%dx),%eax
c3      ret
f048    lock dec %eax
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `decodecode` in the `scripts/` directory in the Linux source distribution that can do this.  You use it by piping the entire Oops message to the script.

Comment: system hangs while kernel oops got printed... how to redirect to file??? using &> ??